# IBM Bluemix enforcing https on spring boot application(Jhipster generated)

Tags: tomcat, https, spring-boot, ibm-cloud, jhipster

I need to enforce https on spring-boot application(jhipster generated) deployed on IBM Bluemix.I am deploying spring-boot war without embedded tomcat, the documentation for cloudfoundry specified that the java build pack itself provides Tomcat configured with a RemoteIPValve, so I need not to add below headers as specified by many answers on StackoverFlow.

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

I have also added below code in security configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
}
```

Still my app is not not get redirected to https.

Also I have a doubt like once if enforcing https is done on bluemix domains , will the same work for custom domains also?

Thanks,
Vasu

Comment: did you try security.require-ssl=true in application properties?

Comment: yes David i tried with that too, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Application Yaml configuration

server:

```
  tomcat:
     remote_ip_header: x-forwarded-for
     protocol_header: x-forwarded-proto
```

The above tomcat headers tell server whether the original request is http or https,

### In method configure(...) which Overrides: configure(...) in ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter, we have to add below lines

> if (profile.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION))
>   {
>                 http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();           }